# I don't understand why my unban command is causing this error

Tags: python, discord.py

So, I'm making a discord bot with discord.py. I am rewriting my bot to use slash commands. I am attempting to write an unban command, however when running I receive the following error:

> discord.app_commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command 'unban' raised an exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'

I don't know what is causing it.

The following is my unban command. It is not the only solution I tried.

```py
@bot.tree.command(name="unban",description="Unban a member from the server.")
@app_commands.checks.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
@app_commands.describe(member = "The member you want to unban.")
async def unban(interaction: discord.Interaction, *, member: discord.User):
    await interaction.guild.unban(member)
    emb = discord.Embed(title=f"User Unbanned", description=f"{member.mention} has been unbanned.")
    await interaction.channel.send(embed=emb)
    dm = await bot.create_dm(member)
    emb = discord.Embed(title="",description=f"You have been unbanned from {interaction.guild.name}.")
    await dm.send(embed=emb)
```

I already tried using a string for the member, it resulted in a different error. Additionally, I tried iterating over a list of banned users, but I received an error upon just getting the list itself - since I'm using slash commands and interaction, I can't use ctx, and apparently using `interaction.guild.bans()` doesn't work. Either that, or I forgot something and didn't notice. I tried using `await` on that and it resulted in an error as well.

**TO CLARIFY**

When I run the command, I input the user's ID. From what I had found previously, it seemed as if I had to make the member argument a `discord.User` object, which would allowed it to automatically convert the ID to a `discord.User` object - using `discord.Member` and the user's ID results in an error relating to the fact that it cannot be converted. This is the main source of my confusion.

Comment: Please provide more details or share the relevant code snippet so that I can help you better.

Comment: @M.TDavis I did share the relevant code block? Plus, I honestly don't have much clarification to provide. All I know is that it's giving me the error I provided. Sorry that I can't provide any further information at this time, this is the best I can do right now.

Comment: now that I think about it I could provide what I did try.

Comment: @M.TDavis When you say the relevant code snippet, what specifically do you need other than the unban command?

Comment: Which LINE gets the error?  Is it the call to `guild.unban`?  If so, that certainly implies that `member` is a string and not a `discord.User` object.

Comment: @TimRoberts Yeah it is the call to ``guild.unban``. What confuses me is when I run the command I input the user's ID, which is what mostly confuses me. Perhaps I should've clarified that in my original post.

Comment: OK, but why do you think that user ID string is being converted into a `discord.User` object?  Who do you think is doing that conversion?

Comment: Oh. I see. I'll look through and try to convert it lol. Probably missed something in what I found.

Comment: @TimRoberts I did the conversion with ``bot.get_user()`` but it becomes None and throws an error anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
I was not converting the user's ID to a user object.
However, I simply fixed that by using `bot.fetch_user(member_id)`.